# IntStream from Random and Random concurrency

Tags: java, random, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

Is it safe to use the same `Random` instance to generate a stream (or parallel stream) and to influence that stream in one of its parts?

Consider the code below.  The same `gen` is used to generate a parallel `IntStream` and to generate a random space every few chars. It runs and completes successfully, no exception thrown.

But is this code thread safe? It appears it is, because there are no invalid (out of range) character values. I think I should be corrupting `Random`'s internal data, since its methods are not marked as `synchronized`, but apparently that's not the case. Why?

```
public class RandomGenTest {

    Random gen = new Random();

    String getRandomText(int len, double spaceProb) {
        return gen.ints(len, 'a', 'z'+1)
                    .map(i-> gen.nextDouble()<spaceProb?' ':i)
                    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        for (int a=10000; a<10000000; a*=2) {
            String text = getRandomText(a, .2);
            Assert.assertTrue(text.chars().allMatch(c -> (c>='a' && c<='z') || c==' '));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that using `limit` on a parallel stream is a recipe for a performance disaster. And it’s unnecessary here, as you can use [`gen.ints(len, 'a', 'z')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) to construct a finite stream in the first place. Further, the explicit creation of new objects via `new Character` is unnecessary, you can let autoboxing do the right thing. But when you change the first `StringBuilder::append` to `StringBuilder::appendCodePoint`, you don’t need boxing at all but can just perform everything using `IntStream`.

Comment: By the way, the bound is *exclusive*, so if you want `'z'` to be included, you have to use `'z'+1` as bound. → `gen.ints(len, 'a', 'z'+1).parallel().map( i -> gen.nextDouble()<spaceProb? ' ':i) .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString()`

Comment: By the way, you can also simplify your assertion: `Assert.assertTrue(text.chars().allMatch(c -> (c>='a' && c<='z') || c==' '));` which is the same as `Assert.assertTrue(text.matches("[a-z ]*"));` (with a space after the `z`)

Comment: @Holger, the `limit()` is not a disaster here as `gen.ints('a','z')` returns an unordered stream. `gen.ints(1_000_000, 'a', 'z'+1).parallel().toArray()` shows the same poor performance for me as `gen.ints('a', 'z'+1).parallel().limit(1_000_000).toArray()`. The real problem is the usage of `Random` instead of `SplittableRandom`.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: random number generation generally isn’t a cheap operation, but I wanted to emphasize that programmers should avoid using `limit` on a parallel stream, especially if there is a concise alternative for constructing a fixed sized stream in the first place. It’s about (not) getting used to it…

Comment: Thanks for your great remarks @Holger. I've included them in the code in case anyone visits this post in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Random`'s [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) spells it out:

> Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.

`Random` is a thread-safe object by virtue of an `AtomicLong` which keeps the current seed, so using it reverses most of the parallel speedup which is the point of your exercise.

Instead use `ThreadLocalRandom.getCurrent()` and avoid at least the contention issue (although by introducing the overhead of `ThreadLocal` lookup). Also use the `SplittableRandom` to retrieve the outer stream of random numbers. This implementation allows random access to stream elements, which is key to goood parallelizability.

```
import static java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current;

String getRandomText(int len, double spaceProb) {
    return new SplittableRandom().ints(len, 'a', 'z'+1).parallel()
      .map(i -> current().nextDouble()<spaceProb ? ' ' : i)
      .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();
```